# A 'check all' checkbox (JavaScript) in a PHP 'while loop'

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I'm looking for a way to use JavaScript in the following piece of code. I want the checkbox with `id = alles` to check all the available checkboxes that are printed during the `while loop`.

```
<form id="andere" name="andere" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
      <fieldset><legend>Selecteer de klassen waaraan je de persoon wilt koppelen:</legend>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="alles" name="alles" value="">Selecteer alle klassen</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
<?php
  $query='SELECT oc_klas.klascode, oc_klas.klas_ID FROM oc_klas ORDER BY oc_klas.klas_ID';
  $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die('<p>Kan query: '.$query.' niet uitvoeren.</p>');
  $aantalRijen = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $KLASSEN_PER_RIJ = 10;
//bereken de colspan van de laatste kolom
  $fill=$aantalRijen%$KLASSEN_PER_RIJ;

  $fill=$KLASSEN_PER_RIJ-$fill;
  $teller=1;

  while($myrow=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
  {
    print('<td><input type="checkbox" id="klas'.$myrow[1].'" name="klas'.$myrow[1].'" value="'.$myrow[1].'">'.$myrow[0].'</td>');
    if($teller%$KLASSEN_PER_RIJ==0)
    {
      print('</tr><tr>');
    }
    $teller++;
  }
  print('</tr></table>');
?>
```

Usually I rely on the `onclick` function:

```
onclick="for(c in document.getElementsByName('klas')) document.getElementsByName('klas').item(c).checked = this.checked"
```

but since the ID's are not identical now, I'm not sure how to tackle this particular problem.
Any ideas?

**Update with a solution given but not working**

```
<form id="andere" name="andere" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
      <fieldset><legend>Selecteer de klassen waaraan je de persoon wilt koppelen:</legend>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="alles" name="alles" value="" onclick="for(c in document.getElementsByClassName('alleklassen')) document.getElementsByName('klas').item(c).checked = this.checked">Selecteer alle klassen</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
<?php
  $query='SELECT oc_klas.klascode, oc_klas.klas_ID FROM oc_klas ORDER BY oc_klas.klas_ID';
  $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die('<p>Kan query: '.$query.' niet uitvoeren.</p>');
  $aantalRijen = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $KLASSEN_PER_RIJ = 10;
//bereken de colspan van de laatste kolom
  $fill=$aantalRijen%$KLASSEN_PER_RIJ;

  $fill=$KLASSEN_PER_RIJ-$fill;
  $teller=1;

  while($myrow=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
  {
    print('<td><input type="checkbox" class="alleklassen" id="klas'.$myrow[1].'" name="klas'.$myrow[1].'" value="'.$myrow[1].'">'.$myrow[0].'</td>');
    if($teller%$KLASSEN_PER_RIJ==0)
    {
      print('</tr><tr>');
    }
    $teller++;
  }
  print('</tr></table>');
?>
```

Comment: I would echo a class name out on all the checkboxes that are part of the "whole" set. Then select them all with something like `document.getElementsByClassName("mycheckbox");`

Comment: if you were using jquery, it'd be as simple as `$('.somecssclass').prop('checked', true)`

Comment: Well, he did ask for Javascript....

Answer (score 2):

Assign a class to all the checkboxs and use document.getElementsByClassName would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Haha, beat me to it x)

Comment: I updated the OP with your solution. It's not working though, what did I do wrong?

Comment: <td><input type="checkbox" id="alles" name="alles" value="" onclick="for(c in document.getElementsByClassName('alleklassen')) document.getElementsByClassName('alleklassen')[c].checked = this.checked">Selecteer alle klassen</td>